# How to set R command line parameters in StatET

Tags: r, memory, parameters, command-line-arguments, statet

I want to set command line parameters like **--max-mem-size=8192MB** or **http_proxy=http:proxy**.

When running R Gui I can do this by adding it at the end of the shortcut pointing at Rgui.exe

Does StatET support command line arguments?

I tried to add it under **Run Configurations** in **Options/Arguments** without success.

**EDIT:**

StatET doesn't support units like 'MB', only unit prefixes like 'M'. So for example:--max-mem-size=8G works.

For the proxy configuration & where to set what see the accepted answer

Comment: Let's see a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run -> Run Configurations... -> Main -> Options/Arguments

[image: run config menu]

[image: run config dialog main tab]

---

`http_proxy` should be specified as an environment variable (at least for use with [`download.file`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/download.file)).  Set those in:

Run -> Run Configurations... -> Environment -> New...

[image: run config dialog environment tab]

---

Note that regardless of your IDE, you can set the [memory limit](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/memory.limit) in R on [startup](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Startup) by adding

```
memory.limit(1234)
```

to your `Rprofile.site` or `.Rprofile` file.

Likewise the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable [can be set](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Sys.setenv) by adding

```
Sys.setenv(HTTP_PROXY = "http://www.myproxydomain.com")
```

to that file.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that my installation is faulty. Could it be a problem that my working directory is not set? I am using Eclipse not Architect. Adding the same in Options/Arguments did not fix my problem, but the suggested function works well.

Comment: Did you try restarting Eclipse?  I don't know if the changes take effect immediately.

Comment: Yes I did, sadly no effect. But you solved all my problems, thank you!

Comment: Having looked into it more, I have the same problem that `--max-mem-size` isn't being honoured by StatET.  Other parameters (`--no-save`, `--quiet`, etc.) work fine.  The argument is passed OK (see `commandArgs()`, but has the wrong value (see `memory.limit()`).  Looks like a bug in StatET. Report it here: http://www.walware.de/it/statet/troubleshooting.mframe

Comment: StatET doesn't support units like 'MB', **only unit prefixes** like 'M'. So for example:--max-mem-size=8G works.